# MVC pattern with CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, cardlayout

I have a Java Swing application with a single large class that via CardLayout replaces the various JPanels based on the various buttons. Each JPanel is built in its own class. I would like to divide the various JPanels into different Model-View-Controllers. My application has for example a welcome page with a button that goes to the login page, the login page can go to three different pages: forgotten password, registration and access to the personal page. All pages can go back. How could I do?

For the moment I've done something like this:

Model:

```
public record Model(String name,String surname) {}
```

MainView:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainView {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel cardLayoutPanel;
    JPanel masterPanel;
    CardLayout cl;
    MainView(){
        frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        cardLayoutPanel = new JPanel();
        cardLayoutPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        cl=(CardLayout) cardLayoutPanel.getLayout();

        masterPanel = new JPanel();
        masterPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        masterPanel.add(cardLayoutPanel);

        frame.getContentPane().add(masterPanel);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainView viewM= new MainView();
        MainController controllerM=new MainController(viewM);
        SignUpView viewS = new SignUpView();
        SignUpController controllerR=new SignUpController(controllerM,viewS);
        controllerM.addPanel(viewS.panel,"SIGNUP");
        controllerM.showPanel("SIGNUP");
    }
}
```

MainController:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainController {
    MainView view;
    MainController(MainView view){
        this.view=view;
    }
    void addPanel(JPanel panel, String name){
        view.cardLayoutPanel.add(panel,name);
    }
    void showPanel(String panel){
        view.cl.show(view.cardLayoutPanel,panel);
    }
}
```

SignUpView:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SignUpView {
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField name,surname;
    JButton submit;
    SignUpView(){
        panel=new JPanel();
        name=new JTextField(20);
        surname=new JTextField(20);
        submit=new JButton("submit");
        panel.add(name);
        panel.add(surname);
        panel.add(submit);
    }
}
```

SignUpController:

```
public class SignUpController{
    SignUpController(MainController main,SignUpView view){
            PersonalAreaView viewPA=new 
PersonalAreaView();
            PersonalAreaController controllerPA = new PersonalAreaController(main,viewPA);
            main.addPanel(viewPA.panel,"PERSONALAREA");
        view.submit.addActionListener(e -> {
            Model model=new Model(view.name.getText(),view.surname.getText());
            controllerPA.setValue(model);
            main.showPanel("PERSONALAREA");
        });
    }
}
```

PersonalAreaView:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PersonalAreaView{
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel name,surname;
    JButton back;
    PersonalAreaView(){
        panel=new JPanel();
        name=new JLabel();
        surname=new JLabel();
        back=new JButton("Back");
        panel.add(name);
        panel.add(surname);
        panel.add(back);
    }
}
```

PersonalAreaController:

```
public class PersonalAreaController{
    PersonalAreaView view;
    PersonalAreaController(MainController main,PersonalAreaView view){
       this.view=view;
       view.back.addActionListener(e -> main.showPanel("SIGNUP"));
    }
   public void setValue(Model model){
   view.name.setText(model.name());
   view.surname.setText(model.surname());
   }
}
```

[image]

The code can be found on GitHub: [GitHub code](https://github.com/user192837/Example1)

Is something correct or am I wrong?

Comment: Your controllers should be `JButton` `ActionListeners` or other action classes.  Other than that, you have one application model that consists of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes, and as many view classes as you wish.  One class for each `JPanel` and one for the `JFrame` is fine.  See my [Simple Drawing readme](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/simple-drawing) for a more detailed explanation of Swing MVC.

Comment: Could you give me an example, based on mine, with corrections? I couldn't find an example anywhere.

Comment: There is literally a link to a Java Swing MVC example in my first comment.  You didn't provide a [mre] in your question, just bits of code, so no, I can't take your code and correct it.

Comment: I changed my question by entering more information.

Comment: Now you're asking for someone to do your work for you.  If you have a specific question about the MVC pattern, ask that specific question.  There are entire books that teach you how to use Swing and use the MVC pattern.

Comment: I thought that like me who could not find a concrete example of how to use the MVC pattern, there could be other people who looking at this page could find the answer.
Also because I have not seen examples of MVC through Swing that would allow you to navigate between the various pages. Thanks anyway for the time taken.